# How to configure all other eth interface to send traffic to one eth port

Tags: routing, bridge

I have an Ubuntu server that has four ethernet ports. Two are unused (in the future I'll use all four), and the first two are being used now. One is connected to a modem so the Linux machine has Internet access. The second used port has an Access Point connected to it. The intention is that the Linux machine acts as a firewall. All traffic should run through it and people connect to the access point. Rather than the Access Point being connected directly to the modem.

[image]

The server has Internet access via the modem successfully. And when the access point is connected directly to the modem it works. Therefore the issue lies in the second ethernet not being "bound" to the port which is connected directly to the modem.

I've received this advice before: "It sounds like you would just set up each interface normally and route the traffic between the two interfaces."

However, I do not know how to do this. I've tried many different Netplan configurations and all have failed.

For example:

01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
      enp1s0: {}
      enp2s0: {}
    bonds:
        bond0:
            interfaces:
                - enp1s0
                - enp2s0
            parameters:
                mode: active-backup
                primary: enp1s0
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Route determines where traffics go, no matter if it's originated from this host or not. Assuming this host have Internet access working, all you need to do is to enable (sysctl) and allow (firewall) IP forwarding and *maybe* set up NAT. No bond whatsoever. For the "AP NIC" just configure an IP that is of a different IP subnet, and optionally set up a DHCP server (that works only on the AP NIC) if you want DHCP for the AP clients.

Comment: Note that if no NAT set up on this host, you will need add route(s) on the modem (and the "outer" LAN hosts) for the other (W)LAN subnet(s) connected to this host (with the modem-assigned IP as the nexthop / gateway) for replying traffics from the former to be able to get back to the latter.